# How i can to return json serializable with django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jsonresponse

I have a custom `apiview` to **query** item in **cart**. I got a instance but when i return `response` it display **error** like this:

> Object of type Order is not JSON serializable

my **views.py**:

```
class getCart(APIView):

    def get(self, request, format=None):

        try:
            order = Order.objects.get(user=request.user, confirm=False)
        except Order.DoesNotExist:
            order = Order(user=request.user, confirm=false)
            order.save()

        return Response(order)
```

Answer (score 2):

So, you have to convert your model instance into json, in DRF it is done through Serializer

As it is specific to model so I am using ModelSerializer

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer

class OrderSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = "__all__"

def get(self, request, format=None):

    try:
        order = Order.objects.get(user=request.user, confirm=False)
    except Order.DoesNotExist:
        order = Order(user=request.user, confirm=false)
        order.save()

    return Response(OrderSerializer(order).data)
```

You can refer from here:- https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer